# Is it bad practice to use Negative Margins or Padding in CSS

Tags: css

Take for example this image below of a project I am working on...
The Blue background is a DIV that is inside of another DIV that wraps all that sidebar contact section together.  To get the `Blue BG DIV` to have the round border and not have a gap because of the parents margin/padding I had to use **negative margins**
`margin: -9px -2px 8px -6px;`

**So the question is, is it bad practice to use Negative Margins or Padding?**

[image]

Comment: Negative paddings are not allowed (and don't work) in css, only negative margins.

Comment: @biziclop thanks for the info, I think I was trying it and it wasn't working, I figured it was something over-riding it so that's really good to know now

Comment: @JasonDavis It depends on how you used them. Like they way bootstrap use them they work fine because of bootstrap take care of all the things around responsive & all. Same here if you are using negative margin then you have to take care of all devices otherwise on some screens they can create the horizontal or the vertical scroll.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No; it's not bad practice, so long as you're aware of the fact you're using negative margins, and that this necessarily 'pulls'/'moves' elements from their otherwise-'normal' position.

Why would you even worry about this?

Comment: Besides, the CSS spec covers negative margins quite a fair bit. (By the way, I haven't written to www-style yet... I've been busy modding, but I see you're helping yourself to these questions :)

Comment: The main reason I was asking about it was I because I didn't want to code a whole site or 2 up using them and then find out that it wasn't good to do so,  just wanted to make sure

Comment: I know this is a really old answer, just wanted to also say you shouldn't worry about "bad practice" with styling, as long as it works on the browsers you want to support then its all A-ok :)

Comment: @Canvas You should worry about avoiding bad practices as there is most likely a good reason for something to be called "bad practice". Although, in this case there is none.

Answer (score 15):

Negative margins are a great way to negate the padding inside of an element for headings etc. I have found no negative results (pardon the pun) of using negative margins. E.g:

```
<div style="padding:10px;border:1px solid blue;">
 <div style="margin:-10px -10px 10px -10px;backgorund-color:yellow;">Full width heading</div>
 The content of the div which is now padded in by ten pixels.
<div>
```

I was worried about negative margins when I first discovered them but have found them to be very useful is so many layout areas- actually reducing div counts and cleaning up layout code.

Comment: Can negative margins have incorrect behavior on mobile/iPad screens. Thank you.