# Position button in Bootstrap Panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys i am using bootstrap panel on a page and i want to align button in the `panel-heading`

I tried using `padding` but it doesnt work it just stretched the `button`

Here is the image of the `panel-group` and in that you can see that the `checkin` button is not aligned properly

Let me know which property i can use

Thank you

[image]

And here is the `html` elements of the `panel`

[image]

Comment: Here a friendly tips for ya. take this as a note and i don't think using negative is a bad practice. :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684917/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-or-padding-in-css

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz See this link i have added a bootstrap glyphicon and its not working correctly http://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/1052/

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz sorry this is the link https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/Wc4xt/3024/

Comment: Okay mike here you go. already fix it. https://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/3025/

I already comment what i did

Comment: Contact me if you need help. :)

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz did you notice that there is too much space in the button text `check in` and also looks very weird.. I have updated the demo please have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/Wc4xt/3026/

Comment: Never mind here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/3028/

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz Hey mate i think you forgot to save the changes that link is still same.. thank you

Comment: Did you mean inside the button? I suggest open another question i will answer at there regards.

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879361/bootstrap-button-glyphicon-in-panel-heading) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `margin` instead `padding`.

Update :- Try set your property position to absolute and use Margin. It will work . Regards.

it is not advisable to use position absolute. Depends, more info can check here.

[Is it considered bad practice to use absolute positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning)

This is just an example

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrxtpoz1/)

Comment: `margin` is working but i have to use `margin-top` and give value as `-5px`.. do you think its nice practice? `margin-bottom is not working`

Comment: there is another trick :) can u gave me the link so i can see it more clearly.

Comment: @fiidoFiradauz actually that page is not on live server.. i am just developing in my `localhost`

Comment: If you set it the position as absolute. and your margin-top wont be in -5px. Thanks

Comment: it is already `absolute` here is the css for button i used `.checkin-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: -4px;

}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set panel-title display to flex, align-items to center. Wrap the title text and set the wrapper's flex value to 1 and that's it. Refrain from using absolute positioning as much as possible.