# Bootstrap button glyphicon in panel heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Hi guys i am trying to display `glyphicon` in `panel` but having some problem with it

Here is the demo page [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/Wc4xt/3036/)

As you can see there button and badge is not displayed correctly

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to see?

Comment: Also, the glyphicon should be specified on an element such as a `span`, not on the button itself, e.g. `<button type="button" class=" checkin-btn btn btn-xs btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Checked in</button>`

Comment: so how was it? fix right?

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz still having a little bit problem but its noting to do with the answer you gave me.. Its working fine in the demo but something else is affecting the badge and button so they are displayed very close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already comment which line should be remove.

Check on

```
<div class="pull-right" >
```

Here a trick everytime you want an icon display in button don't forget to add `<i>` tag

Updated the demo

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/3038/)

Regards

Comment: I don't know where is the wrong tell me why i get vote down?

Comment: @FiidoFiradauz i didnt vote it down and can you please check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/Wc4xt/3037/) again.. Still the button and badge is very close to each other

Comment: i cant remove the class `pull-right` from badge `span` or else something else affects it and badge comes to the second line

Comment: added some margin and it solved the problem... thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. i remove the style on pull-right.  If you notice at jsfiddel i highlighted where is the changes. Btw you already fix it . :) Well play mate. ! :D

Comment: is there any way we can do this without using `<i>` tag  because i want to change the class of that `glyphicon` via javascript and make the button disable.. With your design the problem is as soon as i add class `disable` it doesnt print the `<i>` tag

Comment: change <i> into <span> tag

Comment: about javascript try post another question. Thanks :)