# Responsive Header Positioning

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I developed a header using bootstrap 4.5

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
<!-- Brand -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="logo.png">
</a>

<!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
    aria-controls="collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<!-- Navbar links -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

     <!-- Left -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav left-menu mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto right-menu">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item6</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For the tablet I want to change the arrangement of the elements as follows :
[image]

I
I use media query :
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }
But i dont know how can I transform  left menu (mr-auto) to be bellow the menu.
Thank you !

Comment: Here you go: [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#order)

Comment: Suggestion:- Just check whether the device is a tablet, mobile, or desktop
then based on that device load HTML elements. Here is one example `function detectMob(){return ((window.innerWidth <= 800) && (window.innerHeight <= 600));}
console.log(detectMob())`

Comment: @AmauryHanser I tried order-0 for right menu and order-1 for left men but i have right menu beside left menu instead of been bellow

Comment: @Parth no need to do this to detect the tablet target, I use media querie in bootstrap, which is easier

Comment: @abadou See answer below, I've used the `md` breakpoint,but you could use any breakpoint you want.

Comment: @abadou, Okay that's a great solution :-)

Comment: @AmauryHanser  thank you but not working because I have a collapse div , navbar-collapse that contains left and right menu

Comment: @AmauryHanser I have updated code with collapse div , see update code above

Comment: @abadou The new div is a game changer, you'll need to figure out a different solution, you could use `position:absolute;` on your logo

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the bootstrap's class `order-X` where *x* is the order of the element.

With your current markup, you can add an order on mobile, then change it on desktop.
Note that you could change the markup to only change the order on desktop.

**Step 1:**
Define the order of the element

- Logo will always have `order-1`
- Left menu will have `order-3` by default then `order-md-2`.
- Right menu will always have `order-2`.

**Step 2:**
Define the width of Left menu

- Width 100 by default `col-12`.
- Width auto later on `col-md-auto`.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div class="navbar">
   <img src="//via.placeholder.com/150" class="order-1" alt="">
    <ul class="navbar-nav left-menu mr-auto order-3 order-md-2 col-12 col-md-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto right-menu order-2">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item6</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: thank you but not working because I have a collapse div :( navbar-collapse that contains left and right menu

Comment: I have updated code with collapse div , see update code above

Answer (score 0):

use negative margin on `right-menu` in media queries.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: end;
}

.navbar-collapse, .left-menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.right-menu {
  margin-top: -80px;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
<!-- Left -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav left-menu mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto right-menu">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item item-menu">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item6</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks but I think that not recommand to use negatif margin top , using this i have right menu that is not well centered vertically with logo

Comment: Please go through this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684917/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-or-padding-in-css

Comment: Please accept and up vote my answer if your issue is fixed.

Comment: I still have problems with your solution, I want to scale the same height of the navbar which contains the logo and the right, I have several problems of alignment with your proposal

Answer (score -1):

1. Create two "left menu".
2. Set "display:none" to the left menu near the logo when max width less than 991px and
   set "display:block" to the second menu which is down to the logo.
3. Do the 2nd method in reverse to display the first menu and hide the second menu.
4. Use media query to do this responsive method.

Comment: That's a terrible advice to give. Why would you duplicate your content ?

Comment: It is more optimal to play just on the order of the elements instead of the caches and redisplay them